# Managed Photos Library - Can I use app to delete originals from hard drive?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I use Apple Photo to kickstart my workflow of reviewing and tagging photos. I do "manually manage" my pictures (i.e., what some call the "referenced option) vs. copying them to the Photos library file.

I've created a smart album of pictures I want to permanently delete from my Mac (out of focus, test shots, etc). I'm curious if there is a way to use the Photo app to do this vs. searching through my individual files to do this. This would be similar to iTunes when you delete music, it asks if you want to delete the original files.

I've figured out how to "reveal in finder" - but that only seems to let me do one image at a time. I'd rather try to do this in bulk.

To be clear, I know how to delete pictures from Photos. I'd like to go one step further and remove them from my Mac altogether.